# Privilege too low, setNickname()

Tags: discord

```
            if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "nickname ")) {
            var nick = message.content.replace(prefix + "nickname ", "");
            message.member.setNickname("nick");
            message.channel.send('You have *changed* your **nickname** to "' + nick + '" **!**');
        }
```

I am trying to make a command to change the authors nickname through text. Unfortunately it throws an error of "Privilege too low..." even though my bot has the Manage Nicknames permission, Administrators and is even at the top of the list of roles in server settings. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** According to the answer, the bot of the server is not allowed to modify the nickname of the server superior, despite having the highest role. I ran the code on an alternate account and it ran flawlessly. I just don't get the privilege of nicknaming myself (which can essentially be done via the /nick command that discord implemented)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discord.js implements changing nicknames by getting the GuildMember from the message, and using the [GuildMember#setNickname](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname) method. Here's a simple example of setting the nickname of the user who ran the message:

```
if (message.content.includes('changeName')) {
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) return message.channel.send('I don/'t have permission to change your nickname!');
message.member.setNickname(message.content.replace('changeName ', ''));
```

}

Comment: It's fine, check the edit. Discord bots just aren't allowed to setNickname to the person with the "crown" on the server

Comment: hi Sean, in these day am farming a lot of reputation and i need if you can mark my answer as correct. thanks!